# Apache Solr Search for online users

Tags: search

I'm working on a new site with drupal 7+profile2+search api+apachesolr. Actually it's a dating site. I've developed an advanced search page (view(from search index)+exposed filters), and I'd like to filter online users too. (about on-off checkbox or radio) In addition I'd like to use it as facet as well.

I need some help because I don't really know how to start the process.

Thanks in advance